# Sorting the contents of a vector in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a vector container holding some objects. The objects have various attributes, primarily ints and strings. I want an STL algorithm for sorting the container by its different attributes. 
For example, if a collection of baseball cards has a player name which is a string, and a year the player started baseball, which is an integer, how can I sort the vector container by year number and then later sort it alphabetically by player name? 
I never really learned STL because my professors forbade its use in the past, so I'm trying to learn it now so I can program more quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::sort()` function uses a binary predicate as third argument which can be used to customize the sort order. You can just use two different predicates:

```
 std::sort(v.begin() v.end(),
    [](card const& c0, card const& c1){
        return c0.name() < c1.name();
    });
```

... and likewise for other attributes.

Comment: Thanks, that's much clearer!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is

```
#include <algorithm>

bool operator<(const MyObject& x, const MyObject& y)
{
    ...
}

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Use `operator<` to define the order you want, it returns true if `x` should be before `y` after sorting and false otherwise. From your description is sounds like you want to compare years first, and if they are equal then compare names.

Shame about your professors.

Comment: No, I don't really care about partial orderings in the middle. I just want to sort by name, display to the screen, and then sort by year, and display to the screen.